# What is the faster way to launch any GUI program from the terminal

Tags: linux, debian

What is the faster way to launch any GUI program from the terminal without waiting for its completion and stdout / stderr logging? Now I'm using

```
"program_name >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

but it's too long to type it every time. I'm new to the Linux world but I think that it's should resolved via small bash script, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
"$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Save as for example 'gui'.
Next, allow to execute:

```
chmod +x gui
```

Copy to /usr/bin

```
# cp gui /usr/local/bin
```

Be happy of typing

```
gui program_name
```

!

Comment: You should use `eval "$@" ...`, this is safer than `"$@"` on its own (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079342/execute-command-containing-quotes-from-shell-variable). Also /usr/local/bin` is a safer place than `/usr/bin`.

Comment: If you use `install` instead of `cp`, this will add `755` permissions by default, no need for `chmod`.